# requestFocus on EditText not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'd like that when I start an activity my edit text open keyboard automatically

I'm using this code

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/add_account_et_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/component_height"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/account_name"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
```

It's not working!!

I'm using the same edittext in another activity and it's working!
Why??? Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your manifest file, try **adding the following** to the activity that you want to show the keyboard when the activity starts:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" ... />
```

Another way:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(et, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: Using in manifest it worked! Thanks! But anybody knows why it not works on xml? I have another edit text with the same code and works fine!

Comment: Thats weird. Maybe some other UI-elements interfere. Anyways, glad I could help you out.